# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=org.chromium.content.browser.input.PopupTouchHandleDrawable not attached to window manager

Tags: android, crash

I got this stacktrace in HockeyApp crash report.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   View=org.chromium.content.browser.input.PopupTouchHandleDrawable{a132f39
>   I.ED.... ......I. 0,0-189,232} not attached to window manager     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:402)
>     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerGlobal.java:314)
>     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout(WindowManagerImpl.java:74)
>     at android.widget.PopupWindow.update(PopupWindow.java:1693)     at
>   android.widget.PopupWindow.update(PopupWindow.java:1622)  at
>   org.chromium.content.browser.input.PopupTouchHandleDrawable.updatePosition(PopupTouchHandleDrawable.java:204)
>     at
>   org.chromium.content.browser.input.PopupTouchHandleDrawable.doInvalidate(PopupTouchHandleDrawable.java:229)
>     at
>   org.chromium.content.browser.input.PopupTouchHandleDrawable.beginFadeIn(PopupTouchHandleDrawable.java:274)
>     at
>   org.chromium.content.browser.input.PopupTouchHandleDrawable.access$600(PopupTouchHandleDrawable.java:32)
>     at
>   org.chromium.content.browser.input.PopupTouchHandleDrawable$3.run(PopupTouchHandleDrawable.java:260)
>     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)

We are using webview in someplace to render some urls.
Any idea when this exception can occur?

Answer (score -1):

#### **View** Not attached to the window manager.

Most likely caused by the fact that you are trying to update the position, when the view is not in the foreground. Just check whether that is the case.

Comment: the problem is where should i check. there are thousands of source code files.

Comment: A good place to start would be where you are creating the popup. Do **all** of those files have popup widget. If that is indeed the case then add the checks to verify whether the activity is not null before actually showing the popup.